# I've opened a SSO popup, how do I click a link in the popup?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hyperlink, popup

I'm accessing an SSO through an ASP/C# page and using the following code to open up a popup window:

```
 string s = "window.open('" + getSSOlink(ah1.InstitutionUserID, cardnumber) + "','popup_window', 'width=980,height=600,resizable=yes');";
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

After opening the popup, I need to click 2 links deep into the the popup window navigate to a specific part of the page.  The  id on the first page is id25, and on the second page is cuRewardsLink, and it is the same every time the SSO opens. After the 2nd link is clicked, the user will be directed to a Rewards system.

I'm trying to find a way to open a new browser window that navigates automatically to the Rewards page.  Ideally, they would not see the loading of the first two pages in the popup, just the final destination.  The links within the popup do not have static URLs, there is an AJAX function returning information from the click(s) that create the link.

After the popup opens, I'm not sure how to access the HTML elements in the current browser window (the popup window).  I tried using the WebBrowser class to navigate to the page, wait for loading,and click the links, but got a "ThreadState Exception - ActiveX Control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single thread apartment":

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();                    
browser.Navigate(getSSOlink(ah1.InstitutionUserID, cardnumber));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
browser.Document.GetElementById("id25").InvokeMember("Click");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
browser.Document.GetElementById("cuRewardsLink").InvokeMember("Click");
browser.Visible = true;
```

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated,

Comment: Does your SSO service have a return url option? Just asking the obvious to make sure they haven't already catered for something like this to allow you to specify a page to navigate to after successful login.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that robust.  I get one return url that goes to the main page, which is why I'm trying to use InvokeMember to click the links.